# gauss algorithm shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I have implemented a Gauss-algorithm without pivoting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

def gauss_solve(A,b):
    """
    args: coefficient matrix A of dim(nxn) and vector b of dim(n) 
    of a system of linear equations with n unknowns.
    note: no zeroes on the main diagonal of A allowed!

    returns: vector x of dim(n) which solves the SLE
    """
    while np.ndim(A) != 2 or A.shape[0] != A.shape[1]:
        A = input(["The matrix you entered is not square, specify new input matrix A: "])
#    print "A ok."
    while np.ndim(b) != 1 or A.shape[1] != b.shape[0]:
        b = input(["The dimension of the constant vector b is incorrect, please specify new input vector b"])
#    print "b ok."
    if np.linalg.det(A) == 0:
        return "This linear system doesn't have a single unique solution."
#    print "System does have solution: "
    n = len(b)
    for i in xrange(n): # create triangular matrix
        if A[i,i] == 0:
            return "This implementation doesn't allow A to have zero entries on the main diagonal."
        A[i] = A[i]/float(A[i,i])
        b[i] = b[i]/float(A[i,i])
        for l in xrange(i+1,n):
            A[l] -= A[i]*A[l,i]
            b[l] -= b[i]*A[l,i]
    r = np.zeros(n) # result
    for i in xrange(n):
        r[-(i+1)] = b[-(i+1)] - np.dot(r,A[-(i+1)])
    return r

def test_gauss():
    m = 10
    e = 0.1
    A = sp.rand(m,m)
#    A,b = np.array([[e,1.],[1.,1.]]),np.array([1.,e])
    b = sp.rand(m)
    print gauss_solve(A,b)
    print "Build-in function says: \n", np.linalg.solve(A,b)

test_gauss()
```

The test-function can generate random entries for `A` and `b`. Everything works perfectly fine I think, but I have a matrix here which causes unexpected results:

```
A = [[e 1] [1 1]]
b = [1 e]
```

For `e != 1` the analytical solution is

```
x = [-1 e+1]
```

But I tried some values for `e` and I just don't get the analytical solutions. Even the build in function `solve(A,b)` fails. The first entry of `x` for instance is always `0` (though it should be `-1`, totally independent of `e`). Can anybody explain why this happens?

Comment: In the line `b[i] = b[i]/float(A[i,i])`, you're using the *new* value of `A[i,i]`, which will always be `1.0`, thanks to the previous line.  Similarly for the line `b[l] -= b[i]*A[l, i]`.

Comment: @Michael: LOL. I've fixed the formatting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parallel updates to `A` and `b` are incorrect, since you're updating `b` using the *new* values for `A`.  You need to replace the lines:

```
A[i] = A[i]/float(A[i,i])
b[i] = b[i]/float(A[i,i])
```

with something like:

```
divisor = A[i,i]
A[i] = A[i]/float(divisor)
b[i] = b[i]/float(divisor)
```

and similarly, the lines:

```
A[l] -= A[i]*A[l,i]
b[l] -= b[i]*A[l,i]
```

with

```
multiplier = A[l,i]
A[l] -= A[i]*multiplier
b[l] -= b[i]*multiplier
```

In your original code, the lines for `b` do nothing (disregarding issues of floating-point precision):  the first section of code divides `b[i]` by `1.0`, while the second subtracts `0.0` times `b[i]` from `b[l]`.

Comment: bravo! thanks a lot. i just swapped the two lines. but why did the build-in function solve() produce wrong results while _my_ code was wrong?

Comment: I missed the other bit of your question: in gauss_solve, you modify `A` and `b` in place, so when you solve with `linalg.solve` you're passing the versions of `A` and `b` that you already modified.